# How do I add a Panel to the Rigid Body Panel?

Tags: python

I'm trying to watch the coordinates of an object as it moves during a simulation, and to this end I want to add a new Panel to the Rigid Body Panel, like this:

```
class PHYSICS_PT_rigid_body_worldmatrix(PHYSICS_PT_rigidbody_panel, Panel):
    bl_label = "Rigid Body Coordinates"
    bl_default_closed = True

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        obj = context.object
        return (obj and obj.rigid_body and
                obj.rigid_body.type == 'ACTIVE' and
                (not context.scene.render.use_game_engine))

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        ob = context.object
        rbo = ob.rigid_body

        row = layout.row()                                                                     
        row.prop(ob, "matrix_world", index=12, text="X")
        row.prop(ob, "matrix_world", index=13, text="Y")
        row.prop(ob, "matrix_world", index=14, text="Z")
```

This works if I put the code into `startup/bl_ui/properties_physics_rigidbody.py`, but not if I put it into a script file and try to load it.  It can't find `PHYSICS_PT_rigidbody_panel`, even if I add this line:

```
from bpy.types import PHYSICS_PT_rigidbody_panel, Panel
```

Any ideas how to access class `PHYSICS_PT_rigidbody_panel`?

Also, when I run it by editing the system files, it still has some issues.  It doesn't update in real time during the simulation; I have to move the mouse into the properties window.  I'd also like to see the numbers displayed in scientific notation if they are extremely small.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PHYSICS_PT_rigidbody_panel` class is only present in the properties_physics_rigidbody.py script - it is simply a base class to provide common properties to the other panels in that script.

The step you are missing is `bpy.utils.register_module()`, with the properties you need for the panel you get the following -

```
import bpy

class PHYSICS_PT_rigid_body_worldmatrix(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Rigid Body Coordinates"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "physics"
    bl_default_closed = True

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        obj = context.object
        return (obj and obj.rigid_body and
                obj.rigid_body.type == 'ACTIVE' and
                (not context.scene.render.use_game_engine))

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        ob = context.object
        rbo = ob.rigid_body

        row = layout.row()                                                                     
        row.prop(ob, "matrix_world", index=12, text="X")
        row.prop(ob, "matrix_world", index=13, text="Y")
        row.prop(ob, "matrix_world", index=14, text="Z")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
```